# MATLAB: ert does not generate code for "from flie" block as expected

Tags: c, matlab

I want to generate a C-code from the following Simulink model using the ERT.

[image]

The Coder codes the content of the *matlab.mat* hard into the code:

```
/* Start for FromFile: '<Root>/From File' */
{
  static const real_T tuData[5] = { 0.0, 9.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 } ;

  untitled_DW.FromFile_PWORK.PrevTimePtr = (void *) &tuData[0];
}
```

How can I avoid, that ERT hard codes the values? How can I get a real read-from-file routine?

Answer (score 0):

Given a text file with whitespace separated floating numbers, you can just implement your own reading routine, as follows:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

float tuData[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    fscanf(fp, "%1f", &tuData[i]);

fclose(fp);
```

And then assign the array you just parsed to the target variable in charge of being processed by Matlab code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is not really what I try to get. I don't want to implement own code. This is not the problem. I want to use the Matlab block as it claims to be. The block says, it reads from a file. And I expect this read routine will add to the initializing part of the target code. But the coder puts the content hard into the code and then it is the same as I took data from the workspace as parameters.